# WiX Extended Bootstrapper Application: How to determine which radio button is selected?

Tags: wix, bootstrapper

Here's my setup:

- Compiling at .NET 4.0 (this cannot change)
- Using WiX 3.7
- Using the [WiX Extended Bootstrapper Application extension](http://wixextba.codeplex.com/)

So I'm creating a bootstrapper installation project and though I've got it working, I feel like there is a much more clean and easy way to do it.


Basically, I need to have the user select which environment they wish to use when they install the product. To do this, I use the [WiX Extended Bootstrapper Application extension](http://wixextba.codeplex.com/) to allow me to put some radio buttons on the first install screen.


Getting that all setup was fine, but then I realized that I don't know how to **easily** determine which radio button has been selected. So as I work around I just listed the MSI three times in the bundle and put install conditions on each one.


**Is there a way to determine which radio button has been selected with just one property?** (For example, when I pass the `InstallFolder` property to my MSI as seen in the code below.) **And if there isn't a way to do this currently, is there a way for me to do this without adding my MSI three times to the bundle?**


Here's my code (Notice how I list essentially the same `MsiPackage` three times):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
     xmlns:bal="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension"
     xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">
  <?include Properties.wxi ?>

  <Bundle Name="!(loc.Product.Name)" Version="$(var.Version)" Manufacturer="!(loc.Product.Manufacturer)" UpgradeCode="$(var.UpgradeCode)" Condition="VersionNT >= v5.1">
    <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixExtendedBootstrapperApplication.Hyperlink2License">
      <bal:WixExtendedBootstrapperApplication SuppressRepair="yes" LicenseUrl="" ThemeFile="$(var.Bundle.ExtTheme.RadioBtns.Path)" LocalizationFile="$(var.Bundle.ExtTheme.RadioBtns.l10n.Path)" />
    </BootstrapperApplicationRef>

    <WixVariable Id="WixMbaPrereqPackageId" Value="Netfx4Full" />

    <Variable Name="InstallFolder" Type="string" Value="$(var.InstallFolder.Value)" />

    <Variable Name="RadioButton1" Type="numeric" Value="0" />
    <Variable Name="RadioButton2" Type="numeric" Value="0" />
    <Variable Name="RadioButton3" Type="numeric" Value="1" />

    <Chain>
      <!-- Other Package References Here -->

      <MsiPackage Id="DBConnections_Dev"
                  SourceFile="$(var.MSI.Path)"
                  Visible="no"
                  Vital="yes"
                  InstallCondition="RadioButton1 = 1">
        <MsiProperty Name="INSTALLFOLDER" Value="[InstallFolder]" />
        <MsiProperty Name="SELECTED_ENV" Value="1" />
      </MsiPackage>
      <MsiPackage Id="DBConnections_Stage"
                  SourceFile="$(var.MSI.Path)"
                  Visible="no"
                  Vital="yes"
                  InstallCondition="RadioButton2 = 1">
        <MsiProperty Name="INSTALLFOLDER" Value="[InstallFolder]" />
        <MsiProperty Name="SELECTED_ENV" Value="2" />
      </MsiPackage>
      <MsiPackage Id="DBConnections_Prod"
                  SourceFile="$(var.MSI.Path)"
                  Visible="no"
                  Vital="yes"
                  InstallCondition="RadioButton3 = 1">
        <MsiProperty Name="INSTALLFOLDER" Value="[InstallFolder]" />
        <MsiProperty Name="SELECTED_ENV" Value="3" />
      </MsiPackage>
    </Chain>
  </Bundle>
</Wix>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also asked this question on the project's CodePlex site and the developer responded as follows (here is a link to the full discussion: http://wixextba.codeplex.com/discussions/432341):

`This can now be done using the custom actions feature.`

I've tested his response and found it to be correct! This functionality is available as of version [3.7.4791.32058](http://wixextba.codeplex.com/releases/view/101745). There is also an example included in the [source code](http://wixextba.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/22436#376973) demonstrating how this is done. I've posted the pertinent code below:


Needed in Custom Action c++ code:

```
STDMETHODIMP OnPlanCustomAction()
{
  ...
  if (SUCCEEDED(BalGetNumericVariable(L"RadioButton1", &llValue)) && llValue)
  {
    m_pEngine->SetVariableNumeric(L"RadioButton", 1);
    BalExitOnFailure(hr, "Failed to set variable.");
  }
  else if (SUCCEEDED(BalGetNumericVariable(L"RadioButton2", &llValue)) && llValue)
  {
    m_pEngine->SetVariableNumeric(L"RadioButton", 2);
    BalExitOnFailure(hr, "Failed to set variable.");
  }
  else if (SUCCEEDED(BalGetNumericVariable(L"RadioButton3", &llValue)) && llValue)
  {
    m_pEngine->SetVariableNumeric(L"RadioButton", 3);
    BalExitOnFailure(hr, "Failed to set variable.");
  }
  else if (SUCCEEDED(BalGetNumericVariable(L"RadioButton4", &llValue)) && llValue)
  {
    m_pEngine->SetVariableNumeric(L"RadioButton", 4);
    BalExitOnFailure(hr, "Failed to set variable.");
  }
  else
  {
    m_pEngine->SetVariableNumeric(L"RadioButton", 0);
    BalExitOnFailure(hr, "Failed to set variable.");
  }
  ...
```

Needed in WiX XML (from [examples that come with downloaded DLL](http://wixextba.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/22436#389705)):

```
<Variable Name="RadioButton1" Type="numeric" Value="0" />
<Variable Name="RadioButton2" Type="numeric" Value="1" />
<Variable Name="RadioButton3" Type="numeric" Value="0" />
<Variable Name="RadioButton4" Type="numeric" Value="0" />

<Chain DisableSystemRestore="yes">
  <PackageGroupRef Id="NetFx40Redist" />
  <MsiPackage
    Id="Setup"
    Compressed="yes"
    SourceFile="Setup.msi"
    Vital="yes">
    <MsiProperty Name="APPLICATIONFOLDER" Value="[InstallFolder]" />
    <MsiProperty Name="RadioButton" Value="[RadioButton]" />
  </MsiPackage>
</Chain>
```

Check out the links in the text for the original examples from which these code samples were taken. Hope this helps others in the future.